# Convert a timezone aware string to datetime python which is in format like '2012-11-01T04:16:13.000Z'

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timezone

I have stumbled upon a coding question where I have to convert a timezone-aware string like `2021-11-01T02:08:13.000Z` to a Python datetime object.

I have seen many examples where timezone aware string is like in the format `2012-11-01T04:16:13-04:00`, but for me as you can see the string is little different with the ".000Z" at the end.

I tried the below code:

```
from datetime import datetime

format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
time='2012-11-01T04:16:13.000Z'
date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(time, format)
print ("date",date_time_obj)
```

But I'm getting the error:

```txt
ValueError: time data '2012-11-01T04:16:13.000Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'
```

also tried doing like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
time='2012-11-01T04:16:13.000Z'
date_time_obj = datetime.fromisoformat(time)
```

But I'm getting this error:

```txt
Errpr: Invalid ISO format string:
```

I gone through many pages but was unable to find that particular format and how to convert it to a datetime aware string. Can anyone please help.

Comment: The `.000` is fractions of a second; the `Z` is the timezone UTC

Comment: Python supports microseconds (`.000000`) but not directly milliseconds (`.000`); you'll have to either pull them out and add them separately, or insert another three zeros to turn them into microseconds, or if they're always zero you can match them as literal characters in the format

Comment: ok.. But how the formatting works. What is the correct way to convert this ? sorry I am in a dark here.

Comment: Are the milliseconds always zero?

Comment: @sabik Python *does* support milliseconds (to be parsed by `%f`); the `Z` is the problem here. You can simply use `date_time_obj = datetime.fromisoformat(time.replace('Z', '+00:00'))` for example. Or parse with `%z`.

Comment: @MrFuppes - The `%f` directive parses microseconds (six digits), not milliseconds (three digits)

Comment: @sabik please have a look at subsection 5 of the [technical detail](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#technical-detail) paragraph. `%f` actually parses *fractional seconds* up to 6 decimal places (microseconds). So milliseconds (3 decimal places) also work very well; give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, TIL! The `%f` directive can indeed do milliseconds

Answer (score 3):

You can do all of this using ['dateutil.parser.isoparse'](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html#dateutil.parser.isoparse).  No need to strip out information (dropping the milliseconds), no need to fuss with the formatting string.

```
from dateutil import parser
time='2012-11-01T04:16:13.000Z'
date_time_obj = parser.isoparse(time)
print ("date",date_time_obj)

> date 2012-11-01 04:16:13+00:00
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine , but is there any way to solve this without using any predefined libraries? Just asking

Answer (score 0):

You may change your format like this:

```
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

And convert time like you format by doing this:

```
time='2012-11-01T04:16:13.000Z'
time=time.replace("T"," ").split(".")[0]
```

Or you may format it like

```
format = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f'
```

And you don't have to do anything for time now.

```
time='2012-11-01T04:16:13.000Z'
```

Comment: You may need to keep the zone information `Z` and/or the milliseconds?

Comment: I have edited answer, is it fine now?

Comment: `%f` is microseconds, not milliseconds

Comment: Try preprocessing with `time = re.sub(r'\.\d{3}', r'\g<0>000', time)`

Comment: Also the Z needs to be matched with %z to extract the timezone

Comment: Then it is better to delete answer @Josh answer is already working?

Comment: This does not use any predefined libraries other than datetime , but is the stripping of T or Z reccomended in this case ?

Comment: In alternative answer nothing is done but I don't really know it will work with time zone or not!